# Wordpress ajax post not working can't catch information

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have the following ajax post being made in my wordpress:

```
(function($) {
$('.selectas').change(function() {

        action = 'post_selectas',
        data = {option : selectedValue};

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            console.log("Duomenys issiusti !" + response);
        });
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

Then ajax posting in this page, console says its working but I can't catch info...here is all my functions

```
    function select_skript() {
    if (is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/';
        wp_register_script( 'selectas', $scriptsrc . 'selectas.js', 'jquery', '1.0',  true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'selectas' );

        $translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
        wp_localize_script( 'selectas', 'selectas_js', $translation_array );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\select_skript' );

function post_selectas(){

    $id_nr = $_REQUEST['data'];
    $ids = $_POST['data'];

    return "$id_nr or $ids";
    return "test";

  }
```

function not returning any data test or ids.... where is the problem???

Comment: [Wordpress and AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). See how to use ajax in wordpress correctly.

Comment: 1. You can't use `return` twice. 2. I believe you should `print` the results rather returning them. 3. Check out the tutorial @dingo_d mentioned, your code is missing few things.

Comment: Ok, if I printing results I still can't get them...

Comment: Can't find what I missing..?? can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
<?php

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'select_skript' );

function select_skript() {
    if (is_admin() ) {
        $scriptsrc = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/';
        wp_register_script( 'selectas', $scriptsrc . 'selectas.js', 'jquery', '1.0',  true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'selectas' );

        $translation_array = array(
            'templateUrl' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri(),
        );
        wp_localize_script( 'selectas', 'selectas_js', $translation_array );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_selectas', 'post_selectas_callback' );

function post_selectas_callback(){

    $id_nr = $_REQUEST['data'];
    $ids = $_POST['data'];

    // return "$id_nr or $ids"; // the or in return won't work; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14394447/629127
    echo "test";

    die();
}
```

According to [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) you need to hook your function to `wp_ajax_{function_name}` hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_selectas', 'post_selectas_callback' );
```

And you're missing  `die()` (or `wp_die()`, should be the same) to terminate immediately and return a proper response.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)